# git bundle warning ref is excluded by the rev-list options

Tags: git

We're trying to create a bundle of all the changes to all branches in our repository for the last few days. This command seems to do so, but generates a bunch of output we don't want see in our automated processes:

```
% git bundle create /tmp/some_bundle --branches --since=2.days.ago
warning: ref '4.28' is excluded by the rev-list options
warning: ref '4.30' is excluded by the rev-list options
warning: ref '4.36' is excluded by the rev-list options
warning: ref 'run_lcov_refactor' is excluded by the rev-list options
Counting objects: 4745, done.
Delta compression using up to 48 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1296/1296), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3536/3536), 1.00 MiB, done.
Total 3536 (delta 3019), reused 2655 (delta 2224)
```

I think what the warnings are telling me is that the named branches have no changes in the last two days, which is what I expect.

The bundle command doesn't seem to have any options to quiet or suppress this output. Adding --quiet before bundle fails, as does adding it between bundle and create. Adding it after the bundle name passes it to rev-parse which then doesn't output any refs, so nothing gets bundled.

I can redirect stderr to a file for later handling, but I'd rather just suppress it if possible, so that I don't lose any real errors. Is there any way to do this?

Mark E. Hamilton

---

**Followup:**

This issue came up again, and when I searched I found that **I** had asked about it a long time ago (and clearly forgotten about it.) IAE, since we finally got git upgraded to 2.32 (we've been stuck on RHEL7 for a while) I though I'd check it again.

I might be misunderstanding something, but if the fix VonC referred to was supposed to fix the issue I mentioned it does not seem to have done so.

```
% git bundle create test.bundle --all --since=2.days.ago --quiet
warning: ref 'refs/heads/5.4' is excluded by the rev-list options
warning: ref 'refs/heads/install_sierra_scn_tarfile' is excluded by the rev-list options

% git bundle create --quiet test.bundle --all --since=2.days.ago 
warning: ref 'refs/heads/5.4' is excluded by the rev-list options
warning: ref 'refs/heads/install_sierra_scn_tarfile' is excluded by the rev-list options
```

Comment: We've decided to go with just redirecting the output to a file. That way we have it if we need it, but don't see it in our normal output.

Comment: The `--quiet` was for `git bundle verify`, not `git bundle create`.

Answer (score 1):

> This command seems to do so, but generates a bunch of output we don't want see in our automated processes

And starting with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you won't.
"`git bundle`" has been taught to use the parse options API.

> "[`git bundle verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)" learned "`--quiet`" and "[`git bundle create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)" learned options to control the progress output.

See [commit e0eba64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0eba649e8c2a4271e3bcfb9ebcd358900d425c9), [commit 79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9), [commit 73c3253](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c3253d75e1268946834e72147481fc9a66cc90) (10 Nov 2019) by [Robin H. Johnson (`robbat2`)](https://github.com/robbat2).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ca5c8aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5c8aa8e1cf837613801f26d22f63caea53484e), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`bundle-verify`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0eba649e8c2a4271e3bcfb9ebcd358900d425c9): add `--quiet`
>
> Add `--quiet` to [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) verify as [proposed on the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg182844.html).

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

[`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) doesn't seem to have any options. One potential solution is to use `grep` to filter out the lines you wish to ignore. The `-v` option for `grep` will invert the sense of matching.

Comment: Thanks. I think we'll go with just redirecting the output to a file. That way we have it if we need it, but don't see it in our normal output.