# Redirect git bundle creation output to log file

Tags: git, batch-file

I am working on Windows 7, 32bit, git version 2.12.0.windows.1.

I am writing a simple batch script to bundle a git repository in an unique file. I would like to redirect the output of the command to a log file that I then can inspect, but I encountered a behaviour I cannot undestand.

In any git repository, if I run the following command:

```
git bundle create bundle.out --all > bundle.log
```

I would expect the output of the command to be redirected to the file *bundle.log*. However, after running the command, the file *bundle.log* is created but it is empty and the output is shown on the console as if no redirection was applyed. Therefore, I tried to redirect also the error stream:

```
git bundle create bundle.out --all 1> bundle.log 2> error.log
```

Also in this case, the bundle was created, the two file *bundle.log* and *error.log* were created, but they were empty. Oddly enough, no output was shown on the console. So, my question is, where does this output vanish?

For comparison, I tried with another "similar" command, that is:

```
git bundle verify bundle.out 1> stream1.log 2> stream2.log
```

Applyed to the bundle created before, and the behaviour was the one I expected: *stream1.log* contained the list of refs etc and *stream2.log* contained "bundle.out is okay".

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal, that is, to redirect the output of `git bundle create` to a log file?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41859873/1529709) seems to explain the behaviour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git bundle` prints its output to stderr stream. But it only does so if the stderr stream is a TTY, i. e. an interactive console basically. If it is not, but some pipe or file, then nothing is printed.

You can trick this check by using the `script` utility that records a terminal session or command to a file. So in your case do

```
script --return --command 'git bundle create bundle.out --all' bundle.log
```

And you will have the output in the file `bundle.log`. If you then look at it you will also see why this check is there. (*Spoiler:* This is progress information that is regularly updated and overwritten, this of course does not work properly if you don't watch this in a TTY.)

**Disclaimer:** This answer works for *nix systems and also for Cygwin on Windows. I don't know about plain Git for Windows, the `script` utility might not be available there by default and you might have to search for a Windows port or equivalent or use Cygwin to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the TTY "requirement". Of course `script` does not exist in a regular Windows environment, but at least now I know.

Answer (score 2):

The stderr stream is no longer the only output for `git bundle`.

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git bundle`" has been taught to use the parse options API, and, as part of it, manage its redirection better.

> "[`git bundle verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)" learned "`--quiet`" and "[`git bundle create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)" learned **options to control the progress output**.

See [commit e0eba64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0eba649e8c2a4271e3bcfb9ebcd358900d425c9), [commit 79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9), [commit 73c3253](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c3253d75e1268946834e72147481fc9a66cc90) (10 Nov 2019) by [Robin H. Johnson (`robbat2`)](https://github.com/robbat2).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ca5c8aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5c8aa8e1cf837613801f26d22f63caea53484e), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`bundle-create`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9): progress output control

> Support the progress output options from pack-objects in git-bundle's `create` subcommand.
> Most notably, this [provides `--quiet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238037/6309) as [requested on the git mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg182921.html).

That means the [`git bundle` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L80-L100) now includes:

> `--progress`: (only one remaining with Git 2.41, Q2 2023)
>
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless `-q` is specified.
> This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

> `--all-progress`: (no longer needed in Git 2.41, Q2 2023)
>
> When `--stdout` is specified then progress report is displayed during the object count and compression phases but inhibited during the write-out phase.
> The reason is that in some cases, the output stream is directly linked to another command, which may wish to display progress status of its own as it processes incoming pack data.
> This flag is like `--progress` except that it forces a progress report for the write-out phase as well, even if `--stdout` is used.

> `--all-progress-implied`: (true by default in Git 2.41, Q2 2023)
>
> This is used to imply `--all-progress` whenever progress display is activated.
> Unlike `--all-progress`, this flag doesn't actually force any progress display by itself.

---

Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) simplifies UI to control progress meter given by "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12201fd756bad12c137343d5fd65200f4d0f192d/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> command.

See [commit 8b95521](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b95521edb2a449a9b85064ee49821438d1ffca2) (04 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 12201fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12201fd756bad12c137343d5fd65200f4d0f192d), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b95521edb2a449a9b85064ee49821438d1ffca2): turn on `--all-progress-implied` by default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> In [79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9) ("`bundle-create`: progress output control", 2019-11-10, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5c8aa8e1cf837613801f26d22f63caea53484e) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/228f53135a4a41a37b6be8e4d6e2b6153db4a8ed)), "`bundle create`" learned about the `--all-progress` and `--all-progress-implied` options, which were copied from pack-objects.
> I think these were a mistake.
>
> In pack-objects, "`all-progress-implied`" is about switching the behavior between a regular on-disk "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b95521edb2a449a9b85064ee49821438d1ffca2/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> and the use of pack-objects for push/fetch (where a fetch does not want progress from the server during the write stage; the client will print progress as it receives the data).
>
> But there's no such distinction for bundles.
>
> Prior to [79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9), we always printed the write stage.
> Afterwards, a vanilla:
>
> ```
> git bundle create foo.bundle
> ```
>
> omits the write progress, appearing to hang (especially if your repository is large or your disk is slow).
> That seems like a regression.
>
> It's possible that the flexibility to disable the write-phase progress *could* be useful for bundle.
> E.g., if you did something like:
>
> ```
> ssh some-host git bundle create foo.bundle |
> git bundle unbundle
> ```
>
> But if you are running both in real-time, why are you using bundles in the first place? You're better off doing a real fetch.
>
> But even if we did want to support that, it should be the exception, and vanilla "`bundle create`" should display the full progress.
> So we'd want to name the option "`--no-write-progress`" or something.
>
> The "`--all-progress`" option itself is even worse.
> It exists in pack-objects only for historical reasons.
> It's a mistake because it implies "`--progress`", and we added "`--all-progress-implied`" to fix that.
> There is no reason to propagate that mistake to new commands.
>
> Likewise, the documentation for these options was pulled from pack-objects.
> But it doesn't make any sense in this context.
> It talks about "`--stdout`", but that is not even an option that [`git-bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b95521edb2a449a9b85064ee49821438d1ffca2/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> supports.
>
> This patch flips the default for "`--all-progress-implied`" back to "`true`", fixing the regression in [79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9).
> This turns that option into a noop, and means that "`--all-progress`" is really the same as "`--progress`".
> We *could* drop them completely, but since they've been shipped with Git since v2.25.0, it's polite to continue accepting them.
>
> I didn't implement any sort of "`--no-write-progress`" here.
> I'm not at all convinced it's necessary, and the discussion from the [original thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20191110204126.30553-2-robbat2@gentoo.org/) shows that that the main focus was on getting `--progress` and `--quiet` support, and not any kind of clever "real-time bundle over the network" feature.
> But technically this patch is making it impossible to do something that you *could* do post-79862b6b77c.

`git bundle` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b95521edb2a449a9b85064ee49821438d1ffca2/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L12):

> **`git bundle create [-q | --quiet | --progress]`**

---

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) fixes the `--quiet` option.

See [commit d089a06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d089a06421c86d120f50f05020ca6b833b068dcb) (29 Jul 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a04cef9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a04cef9fd74df0af3f406102897fc265ff53dc1b), 07 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d089a06421c86d120f50f05020ca6b833b068dcb): use `OPT_PASSTHRU_ARGV`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d089a06421c86d120f50f05020ca6b833b068dcb/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> passes the progress control options to [`git pack-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d089a06421c86d120f50f05020ca6b833b068dcb/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects))</sup> by parsing and then recreating them explicitly.
> Simplify that process by using `OPT_PASSTHRU_ARGV` instead.
>
> This also fixes `--no-quiet`, which has been doing the same as `--quiet` since its introduction by [79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9) ("`bundle-create`: progress output control", 2019-11-10, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5c8aa8e1cf837613801f26d22f63caea53484e) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/228f53135a4a41a37b6be8e4d6e2b6153db4a8ed)) because it had been defined using `OPT_SET_INT` with a value of 0, which sets 0 when negated as well.

Comment: This works fine and should be prefered if git version is new enough. I have used this to redirect ouput to a file and now I also understand why is default set to "not write anything if not terminal" :-)